# CrystalReportsViewer, Firefox and no toolbars

Tags: c#, firefox, crystal-reports

I've embedded the CrystalReportsViewer in an asp.net c# web page, and it displays nicely (well, not really "nicely", but you know what I mean, it does the crystal reports "thing") in IE and in Chrome.

In Firefox however the layout is messed up and the toolbars are missing completely.
It's not even a rendering issue, the html simply hasn't been generated.

So, does anyone know how I get the toolbars to be rendered in Firefox?

Oh, this is Crystal XI r2... I think...

In the .asp template:-

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer
 ID="CrystalReportViewer"
 runat="server"
 ClientTarget="Uplevel"
 AutoDataBind="true" 
 BackColor="#FFFFFF"
 PageZoomFactor="100"
 Style="border: 1px solid black"
 DisplayBottomToolbar="True"
 DisplayToolbar="True"
 ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="true"
 HasCrystalLogo="False"
 HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False"
 DisplayGroupTree="False"
 />
```

In the page load:-

```
  SetDBLogonForReport([......]);
  CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = rpt;
  CrystalReportViewer.EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt = false;
  CrystalReportViewer.HasDrillUpButton = true;
  CrystalReportViewer.HasExportButton = true;
  CrystalReportViewer.HasGotoPageButton = true;
  CrystalReportViewer.HasPageNavigationButtons = true;
  CrystalReportViewer.HasPrintButton = true;
  CrystalReportViewer.HasRefreshButton = true;
  CrystalReportViewer.HasSearchButton = true;
  CrystalReportViewer.HasToggleGroupTreeButton = false;
  CrystalReportViewer.HasViewList = true;
  CrystalReportViewer.HasZoomFactorList = true;
  CrystalReportViewer.AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory = @"~/Crystal/";
  SetupParametersForReport([..........]);
```

Sorry, I've had to thin it down slightly.

Looking on chrome the toolbar source is generated with links like this:-
 http://**My*dev*host**/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers115/images/toolbar/first.gif
These links work fine in all browsers, so I think the path is correct.

I'm attempting to run on .Net 4.0.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the code so that it may help others as well as myself to see exactly where the issue may be or how we can help rectify this.. also are you able to use CSS within your creation of the reports..?

Comment: Added some of the code to give you an idea, but it's obviously thinned down. Have you got this component working with firefox? Does it actually work?

Comment: The code looks fine.. I am wondering if it's something to do with FireFox let me look at something on my end first..

Comment: Thanks, like I said, IE and Chrome work fine.

Comment: I understand I read that in your initial this is for FireFox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to upgrade **DLLs in your project** and **runtime on your server** to latest version:

SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010.
Version number is Version=**13.0.2000.0**.

Many improvements have been done so, maybe, firefox compatibility issues has already been sollved.

You can dowload it from [Business Object page](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp).

Comment: Thanks that works, I had no idea I could download those updates without having to fork out for VS and a crystal upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do and the tool bars should display

copy the aspnet_clinet folder (c:/inetpub/wwwroot/aspnet_client) from developement system and paste this folder in same path of the server and application folder. Give the full permitions to the application, then toolbar images will be dispalyed.

Comment: I think I already have it where it's supposed to be. You think it's not finding something? I have the same problem on the dev. system.

Comment: I know but I would actually recommend trying that.. for what I have been using the only way that I could get me ActiveReportsViewer to work for example was to place the webpages in the App_Code folder so what I am suggesting above should do the trick for you.. what could it hurt.. the worst thing that could happen is that it would actually work.. if you know what I mean..

Comment: I agree with you, but it's already there, that's what I meant.

Comment: Oh.. my bad..I thought you meant it wasn't there.. could this be a permissions issue then.. what you have should work..

Comment: I think if it were permissions then it wouldn't work for the other browsers either?

Comment: If it was aspnet_client problem, @JonB would have a 403-Forbbidden error on 'crv.js' and so a 'bobj not definet' javascript error. With any browser.